# .NET Framework Force Reference to be loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, reference, .net-4.8

I created a library with WPF Resources to Design my Controls.
If I now reference these in a new project, I can access everything without any problems.
However, when I start it, it cannot find the reference. Reason: I have not used it properly anywhere and therefore it is not entered as a reference. I have only included the dictionary from the referenced DLL.
If I now somehow access the dll in the code itself, e.g. call a function or create an instance, Visual Studio checks this and really includes the DLL as a reference.

But can I now set it so that a reference is always stored?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bc%23%5d%20force%20load%20assembly

Answer (score 0):

> But can I now set it so that a reference is always stored?

Add a strong reference to the assembly from the application project.

Or dynamically load it or a type in it in your code by for example "call a function or create an instance" like you are already doing.